# How to return HTML in a Javascript/JSX function return?

Tags: reactjs

The following snippet will return and ordinal number if I leave the `<sup>` tags out. But I need them so that I can style it differently than the number itself. Right now it returns `1[Object Object], 2[Object Object]...n[Object Object]`

```
const ordinal = (num) => {
  var j = num % 10,
      k = num % 100;
  if (j === 1 && k !== 11) {
      return num + (<sup>st</sup>);
  }
  if (j === 2 && k !== 12) {
      return num + (<sup>nd</sup>);
  }
  if (j === 3 && k !== 13) {
      return num + (<sup>rd</sup>);
  }
  return num + (<sup>th</sup>);
}
```

Thanks guys

Comment: You know, Strings in JS need some sort of quotes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String - is that JSX?

Comment: What do you think `(<sup>th</sup>)` would return?

Comment: Is this JSX used in something like React?  It's not clear to me what the return value is meant to be or how it will be used.

Comment: can I know why it interprets the unquoted  tag string as an object? I mean, instead of throwing error

Comment: @GrafiCode It's very likely JSX

Comment: @David correct. I'm sorry, I didn't specify

Comment: JSX and JavaScript are two different languages. Choose either JavaScript or JSX, not JavaScript/JSX.

Comment: @LOTUSMS: In that case, what is the expected returned result?  What should adding a number to a JSX element produce?  Did you just want to output that number next to that element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to be returning JSX.  In that case the entire response needs to be a JSX element.  Not a number added to a JSX element (which itself is just an object, and adding a number to an object produces the output you're getting, since it's just trying to concatenate strings).

Something like this:

```
return <>{num}<sup>th</sup></>;
```

Or if empty fragments aren't supported:

```
return <React.Fragment>{num}<sup>th</sup></React.Fragment>;
```

Or perhaps wrap it in an element:

```
return <span>{num}<sup>th</sup></span>;
```

There are options.  But the point is that you want to return a JSX element overall.